# Libgdx Array | removeAll causes error

Tags: java, android, arrays, libgdx

I am not new to arrays, but this is a very strange error. Whenever I try to call the removeAll method on a libgdx array, and I pass in the same array I called it on (To remove every element in the array) it causes this error :

Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index can't be >= size: 2 >= 1

Keep in mind that I'm passing in the same array that is calling the removeAll method. I need to be able to clear the array so I can reuse it instead of creating lots of arrays.

Comment: Can you just re-initialize it as a new array?

Comment: @Orin2005 No, because the array is used in a for loop, which goes 10,000 times. I can't instantiate that many arrays. I need to reuse 1.

Comment: Well I cannot see the code, that is why I asked. I am still confused as to why you cannot just take the one you need to reuse and re-initialize it as a new array. If you cannot use removeAll, can you just use a for loop and remove each element using the index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because it's not designed to operate on itself. The removeAll method is iterating the array as it's shrinking and doesn't expect that.

Just call `array.clear()`